# Memo-style header in RMarkdown to Word

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown, bookdown

I would like to include a memo style header in my Word document created with RMarkdown. The header would look like this:

```
<logo here>                                     <Date here>

TO:       John Doe, Frank Rich
FROM:     Sally Slippers
CC:       Lots of other, people, who, get, copied
SUBJECT:  A line or two describing the memo 
______________________________________________________________________
```

What is the best way to do this? Is there a way to use the YAML header for this? Or should I just create an inline "table" and completely bypass the header?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a .docx file and just edit the header as you want, in the _output.yml add this:

```
bookdown::word_document2:
    reference_docx: my-reference.docx
```

Notice that you have a `bookdown::word_document2 (or maybe word_document)`, just add `reference_docx: my-reference.docx` under that. `my-reference.docx` must be in your project root directory.
Everything you set in `my-reference.docx` like page-style, direction, fonts, color & etc. will be copied to your output document.